# Yii 2. Using a model from a string

Tags: php, yii2

I have a weird scenario, I am getting the model name as a string, so If I wanted to use it, but how do I manage the import class part? Any ideas?

I have tried:

```
    $model = new $tmpModel;
    var_dump($model);
```

Now I get: "Class 'Organization' not found", but I have imported the class manually just to test, but still error.

```
use app\models\Organization;
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT**: I think I needed some sleep. With help of comments here code looks like these:

```
$className =  "app\models\\".$this->modelSave;

$model = Yii::createObject([
           'class' => $className,
        ]);

var_dump($model);
```

Comment: Try setting the string as a constant like `use app\models\CONSTANT;`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have manually set the name of the class:use app\models\Organization, but still fails

Comment: Did you try using the Yii2 autoloader? http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-autoloading.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In YII way you can Use as ..

```
$className = 'path\folder\FileName';
$model = Yii::createObject([
          'class' => $className,
         ]);
```

> This method can also identify
>   dependent objects, instantiate them and inject them into the newly created object.

Comment: I am selecting your answer as the correct one, due usage of Yii :)

Answer (score 2):

You Should use FQN (Fully Qualified Name)  for the model in variable ie.

```
$tmpModel = "app\models\Organization";

$model = new $tmpModel();

var_dump($model);
```

Comment: Thanks!!, I was doing this, but for some reason it was not working (maybe needed some sleep). Remember you need to escape the second backslash: $className =  'app\models\\'.$this->modelSave;